# Store Private/Public Key pair in a Custom Setting

Tags: customsetting, crypto

I'm creating a digital signature for an integration and I've created a private/public key pair to sign the message. According to the [Apex Crypto Class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class),

> This private key should not be hardcoded in the Apex script but should be stored in a protected custom setting or a encrypted fields in a custom table.

but the there's limit for the text fields, and the key obviously surpasses that.

I found a solution that involved splitting the key in and storing it in more than 1 field in the custom setting and then concatenate everything in the code; I don't find this solution extremely good because there are much more chances of something going wrong and consequently messing up the signature.

Does anyone have any other solution/idea?

Thanks in advance.

eclf

Comment: how many chars are in the key?

Comment: Encrypted fields have a limit of 175 characters.  You're keys are really longer than that?

Comment: Well, it's a RSA 1024-bit key, so it's pretty big. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to store the key in a file/document and access it in my code? Can I read a .pem file in my code?

Comment: Have you found a solution?